# white rectangle appearing when links pressed

Tags: css, hyperlink

I am making a simple menu with border-radius:5px on the background when you hover or its clicked.

I notice that for an instant when I click on it a rectangle border, a filled in white appears, which then goes round (in ff and IE11)

www.lo.ee-web.co.uk

I am making a joomla template and pulling int he bootstrap code but NOT using it (leaving it in case I put any plugins in at a later date that might want it)

I figured it might need to overwrite some bootstrap css so I tried adding styling for a:active but that doesn't seem to help. I also notice that if I press a link a second time it doesn't do it so I am guessing that's because of the cache.

Is there a way to stop this annoying box?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set your background-color to transparent.
In your case the css was:

You do have the template.css connected to your html though, and in there i find this:

```
nav ul#mainMenu li a:hover, nav ul#mainMenu li.active a {
    background-color:#3d4d42;
    background-color:#597060;
    border-radius:5px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#efefef), to(#cdcdcd));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #cdcdcd);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #cdcdcd);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #cdcdcd);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #cdcdcd);
    color:#597060;
}
```

This probably causes the white background.

If you change this you might be able to fix it.

Otherwise you can also try to give your css file a new property for the background, making it transparent (or any color you want) by giving it  `Background-color: transparent;`

If that doesn't work, maybe you should try it with !important in it.

so : `Background-color: transparent !important;`

Comment: thanks - tried this - same result. Tried with the !important too. Still same results

Comment: tried adding the background-color:transparent to the original link state and that seems to have solved it... so you were right! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in css:

```
a, a:active, a:focus, a:visited{outline:none;}
```

Comment: Added - this - the dotted line around the outside has gone, but the rectangle is still rendering first with right angle corners, not curves which flash on a fraction of a  second later

Comment: I have noticed that if I comment out the bootsrap css files form the header then this doesn't happen - I wonder if this is just an effect of the over stuffing of code ... (I do really want to leave the bs files in...)